# ASP.NET MVC Default routes accessible via area routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

So far (for brevity) I have one route in global.asax registered like this:

```
routes.Add(new LowercaseRoute("{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
  {
    Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    DataTokens = rootNamespace
  });
```

Where "rootNamespace" is

```
var rootNamespace = new RouteValueDictionary(new { namespaces = new[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" } });
```

LowercaseRoute inherits from Route and just makes all paths lowercase. I also have an area registered like this:

```
context.Routes.Add(new LowercaseRoute("admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
  {
    Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    DataTokens = adminNamespace
  });
```

Where adminNamespace is another namespace, same idea as in the default route, but with the right namespace. This works fine, I can access URLs that look like this:

```
http://example.com/contact  <- default route, "Home" controller
http://example.com/admin/account  <- area route, "Account" controller, default "List" action
```

The problem is that this

```
http://example.com/admin/home/contact
```

also works. There's no "home" controller with a "contact" action under the "admin" area. It pulls the right page from "/contact" but with URL being "/admin/home/contact".

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at the code for AreaRegistrationContext.MapRoute:

```
public Route MapRoute(string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces) {
    if (namespaces == null && Namespaces != null) {
        namespaces = Namespaces.ToArray();
    }

    Route route = Routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
    route.DataTokens["area"] = AreaName;

    // disabling the namespace lookup fallback mechanism keeps this areas from accidentally picking up
    // controllers belonging to other areas
    bool useNamespaceFallback = (namespaces == null || namespaces.Length == 0);
    route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = useNamespaceFallback;

    return route;
}
```

Note in particular the *UseNamespaceFallback* token, which is set to false by default.  You need to have similar logic if you want to limit the search to the area's namespace.  (True = search the current namespace for the controller, and failing that search all namespaces.  False = search the current namespace only.)

Comment: Adding "UseNamespaceFallback = false" to the admin area DataTokens dictionary solved the problem. Thanks!