# ASP.NET MVC3 Area controller accessible from global routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

Perhaps I do not understand correctly how MVC Areas work, but this has got me a little confused.

1. Add an Area called "MyArea" using right-click "Add Area" in Visual Studio on the MVC3 project
2. Create a controller for MyArea: "AnArea" with matching view in the MyArea area.
3. Add "controller = "AnArea" to context.MapRoute's defaults parameter in MyAreaAreaRegistration.RegisterArea method.

So at this point if you start the application and navigate to /MyArea/ it should load the AnArea controller with it's matching view.  If you navigate to /MyArea/AnArea, it will show the same result.

But, if you navigate to /AnArea/, the controller is still found and the following error message is displayed:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/anarea/Index.aspx
~/Views/anarea/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/anarea/Index.cshtml
~/Views/anarea/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Is this the correct behaviour?  I would have thought an area's controller could only be accessed via it's own area and not globally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Default routes accessible via area routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612279/asp-net-mvc-default-routes-accessible-via-area-routes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I create an project with areas, I change my `Default` route as follows:

```
    routes.MapRoute( 
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // defaults
        null,  // constraints
        new string[] { "MyApplication.Controllers" } // namespaces
    );
```

The final parameter limits the default route to the controllers in the `MyApplication.Controllers` namespace.  This insures that the Default route is limited to actions outside of any areas.

**UPDATE**

After a deep dive into the code, I discovered where the issue arises, and have a solution.  Change your Default route to the following:

```
routes.Add(
    "Default", 
    new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ),
        null,
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new {
                Namespaces = new string[] { "MyApplication.Controllers" },
                UseNamespaceFallback = false 
            }
        ),
        new MvcRouteHandler()
    )
);
```

The key is in adding the `UseNamespaceFallback` token.  This will prevent the Default route from looking into any other namespaces.

This is unexpected behavior, and it was a problem I was unaware of which affects a project I am working on.  I will list it as an issue at aspnet.codeplex.com.  I would not call this a bug, but the behavior definitely appears to breach the convetions for MVC routing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the Area controller is still being activated via /anarea/

My Controller resides in namespace: TestAreaControllerAccessibleFromGlobal.Areas.MyArea.Controllers, and I added the namespace 'TestAreaControllerAccessibleFromGlobal.Controllers' to the Default route registration (this is where HomeController was put when creating the new project)

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined in Global.asax.cs?

Comment: No, only the "Default" route with the modifications you suggested in your answer:

    routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}, // Parameter defaults
                null, // constraints
                new[] { "TestAreaControllerAccessibleFromGlobal.Controllers" } // namespaces
            );

Comment: The updated solution works, thanks for looking into it. I did think that it was a a bit strange behaviour ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply a namespace restriction in both area and general route.

In global.asax.cs you should edit RegisterRoutes method just like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", 
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
      new string[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
   );
}
```

That will restrict "//" only to the namespace "MyProject.Controllers"

But also you´ll have to apply the namespace restriction to the Area to restrict "//" only to the namespace "MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Controllers"

For that you´ll have to edit "RegisterArea" method of "MyAreaAreaRegistration.cs"  like below ("MyAreaRegistration.cs" is located at "/MyProject/Areas/MyArea" folder ) :

```
//Some default code stuff
...
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   context.MapRoute(
      "MyArea_default",
      "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      new string[] { "MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Controllers" }
   );
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: There has to be something missing, I created a new MVC3 project, added a new area called MyArea, made the above changes you suggested but the Area's controller is still visible from global ... i.e. //AreaHome invokes the /MyArea/Controllers/AreaHomeController in namespace "MyProject.Areas.MyArea.Controllers".

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be navigating to `/AnArea` whereas your area is called `MyArea` so you should navigate to `/MyArea/`. Here's how the area route registration looks like:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "MyArea_default",
    "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "AnArea", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

`AnArea` is the name of the controller, not the area. If you want to navigate to some controller of this area you should always prefix your url with `MyArea` which is the name of the area.

Comment: I understand this, the behaviour that I'm curious about is to how to stop /AnArea/ from resolving to MyArea's AnArea controller.  It appears counsellerben has found a solution, so thanks anyways