# ASP.NET MVC3 Area action view location

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I met this first time in MVC.
I have area "Administation" and controller in there "News" with action "List".

In debug i got breakpoint at

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    return View(); // Breakpoint
}
```

and i get there

but engine cannot find View "List"

I got error:

```
The view 'List' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/News/List.cshtml
~/Views/News/List.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/List.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/List.vbhtml
```

View exits in location Areas/Administation/News/List.cshtml

Why Razor don't paste Area name into view view location ?

**UPDATE:**

I found solution:
[ASP.NET MVC Default routes accessible via area routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612279/asp-net-mvc-default-routes-accessible-via-area-routes)

```
Route route = Routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
route.DataTokens["area"] = AreaName;
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC expects that you have a matching view for the corresponding action when you call the `View()` method in the controller. So basically its telling you that you have to have a file called `List.cshtml` (or `List.vbhtml`) on the `Views/Shared` or `Views/News/` folder of your project . (Your controller is called `NewsController` and by convention the view is searched on the name You can go to http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3 to see how this works.

Areas are an MVC feature to organize the code on your application, but you are probably missing some configuration for them. [Read this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/areas-in-Asp-Net-mvc3/) for more information.

Comment: I am using areas very often, but how i say this behavior is new for me, i don't know where is the problem.